# Can't find or load main class after setting CLASSPATH for JDBC Driver

Tags: java, jdbc, classpath

I installed JDBC using the Deb Package available online. After installation I set up my /etc/environment.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/openjdk/jdk-16.0.1"
CLASSPATH="/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar"
```

After this point I logged off and logged back in for changes to be applied. Now when I go back to my program

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MysqlTest {

    public static void main (String args[]){

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
        String user = "chachoz007";
        String password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

        Connection conn = null;

        try {

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

compile and execute

```
javac MysqlTest.java
java MysqlTest
```

I get error "cannot find or load main class: MysqlTest"

Turns out that this now happens to all programs, even HelloWorld.java

I have read that this happens because I modified my CLASSPATH in the environment file. What is a way to fix this or should I have not modified my CLASSPATH? but then if I don't modify my CLASSPATH then I get an error saying that the JDBC Driver could not be found.

Comment: @user16320675 I think I understand this answer. After I add the current directory to the CLASSPATH the java command will look for the class not only in /usr/share/java/mysql-connec.... but it look also look for the MysqlTest class in the current directory that I am at, correct?

Comment: @user16320675 Thank you, such simple solution. For some reason the first time I compiled and executed program didn't work and said I wasn't using a password. I compiled and executed a 2nd time and it work. any idea why? anyways thanks, I wanted to understand the solution.

Comment: It is highly recommend not to rely on the CLASSPATH environment variable, but instead explicitly configure the classpath with the `-cp` commandline option.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel May I ask why this is recommended? Exactly what is the syntax of the -cp command line?

Comment: It is recommended because then you don't get interference from tools (like in this case your package manager) putting random stuff or wrong versions on the global classpath which could break your application, etc. Explicitly specifying the classpath using `-cp` (or better yet: using a tool like Maven or Gradle) ensures that your classpath is what you intend it to be. The syntax of the `-cp` is the same as that of  the value of `CLASSPATH`.